# Are both in the same minute?

Tags: python, sqlite

First Q:

With python and sqlite:

Let me say I have a cell in a sqlite table like:

```
2019-04-11 12:32:21.365966-04:00
```

And a variable:

```
now_long = str(datetime.now(pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))) # I am in GMT+1 but need US East Coast
```

I am trying to find out if `now_long` variable match the same minute which is in the cell. Let's say want to compare my cell data and my `now_long` variable and find out they are in the same year -> month -> day -> hour -> min.

BTW: Is this a good approach or maybe I have to make with Epoch. If yes, how?

Thank you

Comment: How did you populate the table cell?

Comment: I have a streaming data, actually I am trying to look at the minute if the upcoming data is in the same min I am gonna update the rest of the row.

Comment: If you are asking "2019-04-11 12:32:21.365966-04:00" coming from streaming data? No, I am inserting for the first time. So can be different...

Answer (score 0):

Your `2019-04-11 12:32:21.365966-04:00` indicates the offset from `UTC` by the `-04:00`.

In order to get the datetime for the cell you can do something like:

```
cell_dt = "2019-04-11 12:32:21.365966-04:00"
cell_dt = cell_dt[:len(cell_dt)-3] + cell_dt[len(cell_dt)-2:]  # to remove the : between 04 and 00
cell_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(cell_dt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")
```

and then you can use the timezone to get the current datetime for that timezone:

```
now_dt = cell_dt.now(tz=cell_dt.tzinfo)
```

Comment: How to know now_long's min is in the same minute of extracted data?

Comment: 'code'db_date = '2019-04-11 18:19:37.994651-04:00'
if now_long[0:16] == db_date[0:16]:
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')'code' I think I did with this